# Should I use different secrets for each deployment of my Symfony2 app?

Tags: symfony, secret-key

I am developing a Symfony2 webapp and I have different deployments (develop, staging, productive). Is it recommended to use different secrets in my `app/config/parameters.yml` or should I use same secrets for each deployment?

Will any problems occur if I don't use the same secrets or will any occur if I do use the same ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using different secrets in different environments is inevitable. To elaborate, you wont probably want to use same database (if database is not located in localhost) for both production and development, for example.

On the other hand, this is why `parameters.yml` put in `.gitignore` by default.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware about the db and sendmail parameters. But I wasn't about the secret.